# Trouble with <select> and framework materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to learn how to use the materialize framework (it's for a uni assignment) I have added the framework to my project but it seems that the framework has somehow vanished the `<select>`, why this is happening?

here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Inscripción en línea</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nivel").on("change", function(){
                var nivel = $(this).val();
                crearListaCarreras(nivel);
            });
        });

        var oferta = {
            'lic_e':['Administración y Dirección de Empresas', 'Derecho', 'Comunicación y Entornos Digitales', 'Ingeniería en Sistemas Computacionales', 'Psicología'],
            'lic_m':['Administración', 'Derecho', 'Ingeniería Industrial', 'Informática'],
            'mae_e':['Administración y Gestión de Instituciones Educativas', 'Derecho Fiscal', 'Derecho Privado', 'Redes y Telecomunicaciones', 'Impuestos'],
            'doc_e':['Ciencias Administrativas', 'Derecho', 'Ingeniería en Tecnologías Emergentes', 'Educación']
        };

        function crearListaCarreras(nivel){
            var carreras = $("#carrera").empty().append($("<option value=''>Seleccione una opción</option>"));
            if(nivel !== ""){
                var lista_carreras = [];
                var costo = 0;
                switch(nivel){
                    case 'lic_e': lista_carreras = oferta.lic_e; costo = 1500; break;
                    case 'lic_m': lista_carreras = oferta.lic_m; costo = 2500; break;
                    case 'mae_e': lista_carreras = oferta.mae_e; costo = 3000; break;
                    case 'doc_e': lista_carreras = oferta.doc_e; costo = 3500; break;
                }

                if(lista_carreras.length > 0){
                    $.each(lista_carreras, function(k,v){
                        carreras.append(
                            $("<option>").text(v)
                        )
                    });

                    $("#costo").val(costo);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://servicios.ver.ucc.mx/icecc/img/logo_ucc_transparente.png" style="background:#002449"/>
<h1>Inscripción en línea</h1>
<h3>Ingreso</h3>
Nivel<br>

<select id="nivel">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="lic_e">Licenciatura escolarizada</option>
    <option value="lic_m">Licenciatura mixta</option>
    <option value="mae_e">Maestría</option>
    <option value="doc_e">Doctorado</option>
</select><br>

Carrera<br>
<select id="carrera">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>

<h3>Datos personales</h3>
C.U.R.P<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Nombre<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Apellidos<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

E-mail<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Celular<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Teléfono<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Escuela de procedencia<br />
<input type="text" />

<h3>Información de pago</h3>
Total a pagar<br />
<input type="text" id="costo" readonly/><br>

Método de pago<br />
<input type="checkbox" /> depósito referenciado<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> tarjeta de crédito o débito<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> en cajas de la UCC<br>

<input type="button" value="Enviar"/>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to read the documentation but it has prove unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't initialized the `select`.

[From materialize official docs](https://materializecss.com/select.html)

> ### Initialization
>
> You must initialize the select element as shown below.
> In addition, you will need a separate call for any dynamically
> generated select elements your page generates.

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

You could initialize it using Javascript or jQuery, I used jQuery tho.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Inscripción en línea</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nivel").on("change", function(){
                var nivel = $(this).val();
                crearListaCarreras(nivel);
            });
        });

        var oferta = {
            'lic_e':['Administración y Dirección de Empresas', 'Derecho', 'Comunicación y Entornos Digitales', 'Ingeniería en Sistemas Computacionales', 'Psicología'],
            'lic_m':['Administración', 'Derecho', 'Ingeniería Industrial', 'Informática'],
            'mae_e':['Administración y Gestión de Instituciones Educativas', 'Derecho Fiscal', 'Derecho Privado', 'Redes y Telecomunicaciones', 'Impuestos'],
            'doc_e':['Ciencias Administrativas', 'Derecho', 'Ingeniería en Tecnologías Emergentes', 'Educación']
        };

        function crearListaCarreras(nivel){
            var carreras = $("#carrera").empty().append($("<option value=''>Seleccione una opción</option>"));
            if(nivel !== ""){
                var lista_carreras = [];
                var costo = 0;
                switch(nivel){
                    case 'lic_e': lista_carreras = oferta.lic_e; costo = 1500; break;
                    case 'lic_m': lista_carreras = oferta.lic_m; costo = 2500; break;
                    case 'mae_e': lista_carreras = oferta.mae_e; costo = 3000; break;
                    case 'doc_e': lista_carreras = oferta.doc_e; costo = 3500; break;
                }

                if(lista_carreras.length > 0){
                    $.each(lista_carreras, function(k,v){
                        carreras.append(
                            $("<option>").text(v)
                        )
                    });

                    $("#costo").val(costo);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://servicios.ver.ucc.mx/icecc/img/logo_ucc_transparente.png" style="background:#002449"/>
<h1>Inscripción en línea</h1>
<h3>Ingreso</h3>
Nivel<br>

<select id="nivel">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="lic_e">Licenciatura escolarizada</option>
    <option value="lic_m">Licenciatura mixta</option>
    <option value="mae_e">Maestría</option>
    <option value="doc_e">Doctorado</option>
</select><br>

Carrera<br>
<select id="carrera">
    <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>

<h3>Datos personales</h3>
C.U.R.P<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Nombre<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Apellidos<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

E-mail<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Celular<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Teléfono<br />
<input type="text" /><br>

Escuela de procedencia<br />
<input type="text" />

<h3>Información de pago</h3>
Total a pagar<br />
<input type="text" id="costo" readonly/><br>

Método de pago<br />
<input type="checkbox" /> depósito referenciado<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> tarjeta de crédito o débito<br>
<input type="checkbox" /> en cajas de la UCC<br>

<input type="button" value="Enviar"/>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```